# CAML query for child properties

Tags: csom, caml-query, c-sharp

I have a CSOM query like this one:

```
_context.Load(currentItems,
   lis => lis.Include(
          i => i.RoleAssignments.Include(
               ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings,
               ra => ra.RoleDefinitionBindings.Include(
                     rdb => rdb.Name
                     ).Where(
                     rdb => rdb.Name != "Limited Access"
                     )
               ).Where(
               ra => ra.Member.LoginName.StartsWith("SharingLink"))
               )
  );
```

I want to load all items that, in their RoleAssignments, the Member LoginName starts with "SharinLink" text. This is however not possible because CSOM cannot use *StartsWith* function.

There is also the option of using the BeginsWith from a CAML query. However, I don't know how to tell the query that it needs to use a ListItem.RoleAssignments.Member.LoginName property. Is this possible? Considering there are various RoleAssignments per ListItem.

Thanks in advance.